# How can I change the color of the component that I created after calling?

Tags: react-native

For the below logout component I want to change its TintColor and text color , what should I code?

I tried adding style here but it doesn't work.

```
        <MenuItems listingname="Logout"
            onPress={() => {
                this.RBSheet.close();
                this.props.notifyCountrUpdtHndlr(0)
                AuthHelpers.logout(this.props.navigation,true);
            }}
            imagesource ={IMAGE.LOGOUT_ICO}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go inside MenuItems component and change the style there
(click on MenuItems component name and press `F12` key)

just find Image and Text Component and add your styles
(to find Image and Text component inside MenuItems search listingname and imagesource)

```
<Image style={yourNewStyle}/>

<Text style={yourNewStyle}> </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

The very basic method you can use Inline CSS

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
  This component has a red background
</div>
```

And Another Method is Using CSS class selector

```
.red-background {
   background-color: red;
 }

// component
<div className="red-background">
   This component has a red background
</div>
```

Also you can change the color of the component dynamically like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    };
  }

  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState({
      backgroundColor: '#123456'
    });
  }

  render() {
     return (
        <View style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor,    height:100, width: 100}}>
        <Text onPress={this.changeColor}>Click Me!</Text>
       </View>
         );
    }
}

export default MyComponent;
```